# Trouble scaling an outline in Adobe Illustrator CC (2017)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize

So I'm attempting to make another outline of the vector (in white) within the actual vector shape (black), but scaling the image doesn't keep the vector points aligned with each other. Is there a way to create that outline and have it correspond to the vector path of the original shape (black)?

[image: example image]

I'd like the white line to be within the original shape, but cant figure out how to keep the scale bound to the vector points of the original image. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried grouping the elements before scaling them?

Comment: How do your layers look like? Can you add a screenshot? But it looks like you're not selecting everything you want to scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the extra outline not scaling you probably have the layer locked or aren't selecting it for some other reason, but it's hard to know without seeing your layers and your selection...

To answer "Is there a way to create that outline and have it correspond to the vector path of the original shape?"...

Yes. Add a stroke using the Appearance panel (*Window → Appearance*) and with that stroke selected in the panel, use the "fx" button to add an Offset Path... effect to that stroke.

[image]

Comment: Worked out wonderfully! Thanks so much for the help!